# Subtract two same-sized matrices with string header rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, read.csv

I have two matrices imported from csv files. They have the same number of rows and columns. I need a third matrix which would be the element-wise subtraction of the two matrices.

```
t1 <- read.csv("/matrix_1.csv", check.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
t2 <- read.csv("/matrix_2.csv", check.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

t1 looks like this:

```
Name,A,B,C,D,E
A,10,5,14,3,0
B,5,21,6,1,0
C,14,6,19,6,4
D,3,1,6,7,1
E,0,0,4,1,3
```

and t2 like this:

```
Name,A,B,C,D,E
A,4,5,4,3,0
B,5,2,6,1,0
C,1,6,1,6,4
D,3,1,1,7,1
E,0,0,3,1,2
```

Trying:

```
t3 = t1 - t2
```

doesn't work, it raises:

> Warning message: In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘-’ not meaningful for
>   factors

Probably because t1 and t2 contain strings headers for rows and columns (which are important for the rest of the operations).

How would I go about subtracting two matrices without taking into account the strings for each row and column?

Comment: You should never have read in the dataframe header rows in the first place. Use `read.csv(header=T...)` or `read.csv(skip=1, ...)`. Or else read in as dataframes, then coerce to `as.matrix(t1) - as.matrix(t2)`

Comment: The string header rows are ***column names***, because they're dataframes (not matrices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just omit the first column. One way to do this is with negative indexing

```
t3 <- t1[,-1] - t2[,-1]
```

If needed, you could merge back in the first column

```
t3 <- cbind(t1[,1, drop=FALSE], t1[,-1] - t2[,-1])
```

Of course this assumes all your rows already match up.

Answer (score 2):

You should never have read in the dataframe header rows in the first place. Use `read.csv(header=T...)` or `read.csv(skip=1, ...)`.

Or else read in t1,t2 as dataframes, then coerce to matrices:

```
as.matrix(t1) - as.matrix(t2)
```

Comment: What about the first column?  It's still there when you do `read.csv(skip = 1, header = FALSE)`.  You would need `read.csv(skip = 1, header = FALSE, row.names = 1)`.  Then you can subtract the two

Comment: In fact, if you just did `read.csv(row.names = 1)` on both it would do the trick nicely, keeping the header and moving the first column to the row names.  Then `t1 - t2` works, I've tested it